# Property 'clientX' does not exist on type 'Event' Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, mouseevent

I'm using TypeScript with Angular 6 and am trying to utilize my mouse events.

However, upon this code:

```
if (event.clientX < 260){
  return [x + 20, ny - 190]
}
else {
  return [x - 240, ny - 190]
}
```

I receive an error stating

> "Property 'clientX' does not exist on type 'Event'.

The code still functions as intended.

How can I resolve this so it doesn't seem I have an error?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can declarate the parameter type where you are passing the event as follows,

```
someFunc(event: MouseEvent): void  { 
  if (event.clientX< 260){
    return [x+20, ny - 190]
  }
  else {
    return [x-240, ny - 190]
  }
}
```